# Vue 3 basic website not work on webOS LG TV

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, router, webos

I have basic vue3 website, that works on every platform, except webOS LG TV, the page cannot loaded. Loaded only favicon and meta title.

Dont know where is problem. Thank you for advice

I tried this -  https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: which webos tv are you using? It may not support the es that is being generated. https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/specifications/web-api-and-web-engine check the browser engine and check by adding "Chrome > 30" to your browserlist config

Comment: @Kiran can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: LG TVs before 2017 have chrome 38 as their browser, so many es6 features may not work in them - https://caniuse.com/?search=es6. There may be some js feature that is not supported and is causing the app to not render.